# How to change my Delete SQL query into LINQ

Tags: linq

I'm a little bit new in LINQ field.I have a Delete query like this:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE FK IN (SELECT ID FROM Table2 WHERE UserId = @UId)
```

How can I change it into a LINQ query?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea

```
var itemQuery = from cartItems in db.SalesOrderDetails
              where cartItems.SalesOrderID == 75144
              select cartItems.ProductID;


var myProducts = from p in db.Products
                where itemQuery.Contains(p.ProductID)
                select p;

foreach (var detail in myProducts )
{
    db.myProducts.DeleteOnSubmit(detail);
}

try
{
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    // Provide for exceptions.
}
```

Comment: instead of a foreach you could also do  `db.myProducts.DeleteAllOnSubmit(myProducts);`